# Display bitwise value as an integer in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, mask

I'm trying to display the last 4 bits of a 16 bit number as the "password" 
The loop is initialized with a mask starting at the 4th bit from the end, and adds up the value of the bits (4th bit, 2^3, 3rd 2^2, and so on), but it always returns 0.

There are two functions, one prompts the user for the code that will be used as the 16 bit number the 4 bits will be taken from.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int get_code();
void display_binary(int num);

int main()
{
int code, password, signal, missiles, ctr;

code = get_code();
printf("\nThe code is %d\n", code);
printf("The code in Hexadecimal: %X\n", code);
printf("The code in binary:");
display_binary(code);

int sum = 0;
int mask = 1 << 3;
for (ctr = 3; ctr >= 0; ctr--)
{
    if ((mask & code) == 1)
        sum = sum + pow(2, ctr);
    else
        sum = sum + 0;
    mask >> 1;

}

printf("\n\nThe password is %d\n", sum);


_getch();
return 0;
}

/*===============================
    get_code
    no input
    int output
    prompts user for number
===============================*/
int get_code()
{
    int num;
    do
    {
         printf("Enter a whole number between -4000 and 4000, inclusive: ");
         scanf("%d", &num);
    } while (num > 4000 || num < -4000);
    return num;
}

/*================================
    display_binary 
    int input
    no output
    displays number in binary 
 ===============================*/
void display_binary(int num)
{
    int mask = 1 << 15;
    int ctr;
    for (ctr = 1; ctr <= 16; ctr++)
    {
        if ((mask & num) == 0)
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
        if ((ctr % 4) == 0)
            printf(" ");
        mask = mask >> 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: test for > 0 instead of equal 1. But why not `printf("%X", code & 0x0F)`?

Comment: > 0 still resulted in 0, `printf("%X", code & 0x0F)` did result with the correct bit addition. Wasn't taught in our lectures or books, but greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't **ever** use `pow` for calculating integer powers of integers. Especially *never* use it to calculate powers of 2. Use bitshifts, i.e. `1ULL << exponent` instead for powers of 2

Comment: Also  `sum = sum + 0;` now that's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors in this code that prevented the 'password' to be displayed:

```
int sum = 0;
int mask = 1 << 3;
for (ctr = 3; ctr >= 0; ctr--)
{
    if ((mask & code) == mask) // <=== not '1' but 'mask'
        sum = sum + pow(2, ctr);
    else
        sum = sum + 0;
    mask >>= 1;  // <=== '=' was missing

}
```

But of course you could do simply

```
int password = code & 0x0F;
```

The reason of `(mask & code) == mask` is because `mask & code` result will have all `code` bits cleared except the one in `mask`. You could also, as commented above, do simply

```
if (mask & code)
```

since any non zero result of `mask & code` is evaluated to true, in C.

Besides `pow()` is overkill to calculate a power of two, since you could use bit shifting, as you did elsewhere in the code

```
sum = sum + (1 << ctr);
```

or

```
sum += 1 << ctr;
```